# Getting content from the Strapi CMS using findOne if the value of the property matches

Tags: node.js, database, next.js, strapi

I have a pet project NextJS with Strapi CMS for issuing documents to users by phone number and order number . At the moment I am using findOne and slug search to find the order I need:

```
"use strict";

const { createCoreController } = require("@strapi/strapi").factories;

module.exports = createCoreController(
  "api::document.document",
  ({ strapi }) => ({
    async findOne(ctx) {
      const { id: slug } = ctx.params;
      const { query } = ctx;
      if (!query.filters) query.filters = {};
      query.filters.slug = { $eq: slug };
      const entity = await strapi.service("api::document.document").find(query);
      const { results } = await this.sanitizeOutput(entity, ctx);

      return this.transformResponse(results[0]);
    },
  })
);
```

then, after receiving the order, on the client side, if the phone number entered by the user matches the phone number in the order, I give the user the documents.

```
        const phone = e.target["phone"].value;
        const order = e.target["order"].value;

        try {
            fetch(`${apiURL}/documents/${order}?populate=documents`)
                .then((res) => {
                    if (!res.ok) {
                        Promise.reject(res);
                        setError(true);
                    }
                    return res.json();
                })
                .then((data) => {
                    if (data && phone === data.data?.attributes.phone) {
                        setDocs(data.data.attributes.documents.data);
                        return;
                    }
                });
        } catch () {
            setError(true);
        }
```

The problem is that Strapi always returns order if the slug value matches, and in this case you can access documents from the order through the developer tools in the browser, through the networks tab

I want to make sure that the phone number is included in the request, and if the slug or phone number does not match those in the order, the order is not sent to the client.

Something like this

`${apiURL}/documents/${order}?phone=${phone}`